# Replace dot if behind or infront of a number

Tags: regex

I have loads of lines which looks like this:

```
"d6.der.ld"   "5.3355"    "0.4555"
```

I've done this in PowerShell which replaces the dot with a comma (,)

```powershell
(Get-Content "data.tsv") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\.", ","} | Set-Content "data.tsv"
```

Which works fine. But i would like it to only replace if a number 0-9 is both infront and behind the dot.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to format your numbers with comma separator instead of a period. If you have access to the program that makes `data.tsv`, consider changing it "at the source" to let you choose the format. This is much more reliable than using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched dots with the string you want.

```
(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)
```

It matches all the dots only if it's preceded and followed by a digit character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
{$_ -replace "([0-9]<$1>)\.([0-9]<$2>)", "$1,$2"}
```

<$1> means you save the digit inside $1, allowing you to reuse it after

Comment: Looks like you missed another pair of parenthesis.

Comment: That removes the 0 preceeding the comma.

Comment: Yes I had actually missed a pair of parenthesis, thankfully mentioned by @PacoAbato